# Add single item to linq to sql query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I would like to add a single item to the results of a linq query. I know it's not possible to join a local source and a SQL source. So, is it possible to construct a query to do the same as this?

```
SELECT ID FROM Types
UNION
SELECT 1
```

The best I've come up with is this:

```
List<int> OrgList = DBContext.Types.Select(b => b.ID).ToList();
OrgList.Add(1);
```

but I'd rather add the item beforehand and still have an IQueryable. Or is there a good reason to not do it this way?

Comment: `OrgList` and `OrganisationList` are both same type? However, if you need `union` you can use [Queryable.Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, my mistake, thanks. I've tried Union and couldn't get it to work but I'll give it another go and post the problem.

Comment: remember, it expect a list when you do union. So you have to pass `.Union(new List<int>() {1});`

Comment: Not sure what I was doing incorrectly before, it works fine, but I think I was too intent on returning an IQueryable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must get the data from the db and then add the new item like you have done in your code.

The only way to have an `IQueryable` would be to deffer the adding of the new item to the point were the query is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Union:

```
var query = DBContext.Types.Select(b => b.ID).ToList().Union(new[]{1});
```

Not tested but it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try Concat

```
var result = DBContext.Types.Select(p => p.ID)
             .Concat(new List<int>() { 1 }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try this and had the same problem as I did with Union, but I think it was my understanding of how linq to SQL works which was the problem.